HDMI sound is cutting out intermittenly
I'm trying to address an issue with sound over HDMI I am having but have had no luck fixing it. The sound will cuts out from time to time. Usually it happens several times in a row, then will be fine for maybe 15 seconds, if I am lucky.
I heard that this is a Linux kernel issue that was addressed in version 6.11, so I updated. The problem persists.
I have tried 3 different cables, all with similar results. I have Windows dual-booted, HDMI sound works perfect on Windows.
Does anybody have any idea what I can do to troubleshoot this issue? I'll share some system details here, but let me know what other information is required.
-Ubuntu 24.04
-AMD CPU/GPU
-KDE Plasma desktop
-Previous kernel: 6.8.0-48-generic
-Current kernel: 6.11.0-061100-generic
